# Save two different return types in one variable

Tags: c++, c++11

In the following code, I want to use params to save two different return types. So I could remove redundant code. But, I don't have a good solution here.

My version:

```
if (...) { 
    auto params = gather_quantized_params(_params);
    // the following lines are just duplicated in different branches 
    auto results = _lstm_impl<FullLayer, FullBidirectionalLayer>(
        input, params, hx[0], hx[1], num_layers, dropout_p, train, bidirectional); 

   return results;
} else {
    auto params = gather_quantized_params_fp16(_params);
    auto results = _lstm_impl<FullLayer, FullBidirectionalLayer>(
        input, params, hx[0], hx[1], num_layers, dropout_p, train, bidirectional);
    return results 
}
```

===
Header of related functions:

```
    static std::vector<QuantizedCellParamsFP16> 
gather_quantized_params_fp16(TensorList params) {
    ...}

  static std::vector<QuantizedCellParams> 
    gather_quantized_params(TensorList params) { 
    ...} 

template<template<typename,typename> class LayerT, 
  template<typename,typename> class BidirLayerT, 
  typename cell_params, typename io_type> 
std::tuple<io_type, Tensor, Tensor> _lstm_impl(
         const io_type& input,
         const std::vector<cell_params>& params, const Tensor& hx, const Tensor& cx,
         int64_t num_layers, double dropout_p, bool train, bool bidirectional) { ...}
```

===
When I was using the approach suggested in the answer(which is really cool), I encounter the following this error - "error: use of ‘auto’ in lambda parameter declaration only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14".

Seems that I need to have another solution which avoids auto in lambda parameter.

Comment: Side issue: I believe that using an `_` for symbol (variable and function) names at the beginning of the name is reserved for the implementation, so it is not a good practice to use that.

Comment: @Chipster just if they are followed by an uppercase. I.e. `_Upper` is reserved `_lower` is ok

Comment: Except at global scope where all leading underscores are reserved. [Might as well just link to the whole ruleset.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) Rather than remember the rules I just don't use leading underscores anywhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend doing:

```
auto implement_params = [&](auto params) {
    auto results = _lstm_impl<FullLayer, FullBidirectionalLayer>(
        input, params, hx[0], hx[1], num_layers, dropout_p, train, bidirectional); 

   return results;
}; 

if(...) {
    return implement_params(gather_quantized_params(_params));
} else {
    return implement_params(gather_quantized_params_fp16(_params));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. There is an error: "error: use of ‘auto’ in lambda parameter declaration only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14". Do you have a workaround for that?

Comment: My code uses a feature that was added to the language 5 years ago, in 2014. Your compiler might be using C++11 by default (which is an even older release). Add the compiler flag -std=c++14 to the list of command line arguments you’re using to compile it, and the code should compile fine.

Comment: It's actually a big project which I am not allowed to add that flag.